# Javascript/jQuery not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

This code works in all browsers except for IE. Anything I can do to add support for it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentArrayNum = 2;
  $('#names').on({
    blur: function() {
        currentArrayNum += 1;
        var name = $("<p><input class='input' type='text' name='guests[]' value='' /></p>");

        var nullFields = 0;
        $(this).closest('div#names').find('input.input').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() == ""){
                nullFields++;
            }
        });
        console.log(nullFields);

        if(nullFields <= 1){
          $('#names').append(name.fadeIn(500));
          $('#leftbox').scrollTop($('#leftbox')[0].scrollHeight);
        }
    }
}, 'input');
 });
</script>
```

It should mean that extra input fields are added. You can see it in action (in FF, Chrome, Safari etc) under 'Enter names for the guestlist' [here](http://cambridge.guestvibe.com).

**EDIT**

Tested in IE9 but doesn't work for me.

I should also ask if there's a way of testing in different versions of IE (and othe browsers) on a Mac?

Comment: In what version(s) of internet explorer are you having the problem? *edit* it works fine for me in IE9.

Comment: What isn't happening in IE? And any specific version(s) you're testing on?

Comment: It also works in IE8 (though the formatting is a little off)

Comment: Well one problem is that your page is going to be really weird for IE, because those conditional comments will give you two `<html>` tags.  That'll leave the `<script>` tags that come before those in some weird state, which could easily confuse older versions of IE.  You should just use [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) as your guide.

Answer (score 6):

Note that in some (all?) versions of IE, you need to have developer ("F12") tools open for `console.log` to work, otherwise `console` is undefined and so `console.log()` throws an error.

That may be your issue.

Comment: `if (console) console.log(...);`

Comment: You could add how to test for it: `if ('console' in window) { /* console.log is supported */ }`

Comment: @RussCam I believe that would throw an error where console is not defined. Should be `if(window.console)`

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is about a week old but Im not sure if you found a solution or the reason for the cross-browser issues. I was recently working on a custom modal pop up window and I needed to find my scrollTop. Trust me, I love jQuery to death and I use it everyday but sometimes you need to use some good ol' javaScript. I.E accesses the `body` of the DOM differently than say Chrome or FF.

```
//I.E.
document.documentElement.scrollTop;

//Chrome, FF, etc.
document.body.scrollTop;
```

Basically, create a script that detects the user's browser and then include a conditional statement that will assign the value the appropriate way.

```
//Detect Browser
if (clientBrowser == "IE") {

    currTopPos = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
} else {

    currTopPos = document.body.scrollTop;
}
```

I created a script for one of the current projects Im working on, let me know if you would like to take a look at it.